# Automatically log user into existing ASP.NET MVC 4 web app based on whether user has an Active Directory account

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, iis-10

I hope someone can help me with the following scenario, as I've been trolling the web for without success for a couple of days now.

The scenario I'm facing is how do I automatically bypass the login screen and go directly to the dashboard if the user exists in Active Directory (AD)?  If the user does not exist i.e. user does not have an Active Directory (AD) account redirect the user to a login page.

Attached is a picture to explain the process better.

[image]

If I run the ASP.NET MVC 4 web app using "IIS Express" the username and domain are correct, and I automatically get logged in because my credentials are correct for e.g:

```
username   => "username"
domain     => "domain"
```

But If I run the solution on my "Local IIS" the credentials are incorrect because IIS logs in using the following credentials:

```
web.config setting (identity impersonate="false")
username   => "NT AUTHORITY\\IUSR"
domain     => "IIS APPPOOL"

web.config setting (identity impersonate="true")
username   => "NT AUTHORITY\\IUSR"
domain => "NT AUTHORITY"
```

> [15/11/2017] Update

It seems like it's failing on UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity as I built in basic logging so I can get a better understanding of where it's failing on the server.

The error I'm getting is "An operations error occurred.".

The settings in IIS of interest are as follows:

**"Application Pools"** Advanced Settings...

```
Enable 32-Bit Applications  = True
Identity                    = NetworkService
```

And the Websites **Authentication** setting are as follows:

```
Anonymous Authentication    = Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation       = Enabled
Basic Authentication        = Disabled
Forms Authentication        = Disabled
Windows Authentication      = Enabled
```

> [16/11/2017] Update
>
> Turned off Impersonation in IIS and set the Identity to ApplicationPoolIdentity

Here are my values from the log file I created:

```
[2017-11-16 07:17:52 AM]    Windows username    => username (e.g. jdoe)
[2017-11-16 07:17:52 AM]    Domain              => IIS APPPOOL
[2017-11-16 07:21:18 AM]    Windows username    => username (e.g. jdoe)
[2017-11-16 07:21:18 AM]    Domain              => IIS APPPOOL
[2017-11-16 07:23:38 AM]    Windows username    => username (e.g. jdoe)
[2017-11-16 07:23:38 AM]    Domain              => IIS APPPOOL
```

> [16/11/2017] Solution

**"Application Pools"** Advanced Settings...

```
Enable 32-Bit Applications  = True
Identity                    = NetworkService
```

And the Websites **Authentication** setting are as follows:

```
Anonymous Authentication    = Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation       = Disabled
Basic Authentication        = Disabled
Forms Authentication        = Disabled
Windows Authentication      = Enabled
```

Cheers,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Windows Authentication in your Local ISS. 
[ISS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqZj2.png)

This should solve the issue you are having with your local ISS.

Comment: Thanks Sychal I did that and it works perfectly on my "Local IIS" but when I set the same settings on our server it still doesn't seem to work...  Happy Freaking Days :-(.

Comment: Howzit Sychal please see my updated post, especially the section referring to the IIS Application Pool and Website Authentication settings.

Comment: Try turning off Impersonation in IIS. I also usually set the Identity to ApplicationPoolIdentity (more info about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

Comment: Cool I'll try that and see if it fixes my issue.

Comment: Howzit Synchal still no luck, please see my updated post when turning off Impersonation in IIS and setting the Identity to ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Comment: Howzit Synchal I finally managed to sort it out, please see my updated post for the solution on our company server.  Thanks very much for all your help ;-).

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. And happy to help :-)

Comment: Thanks :-D, I think I owe you a beer if you're ever in Cape Town Hahahaha.